# Add "more" html at then end of an element using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an empty div at the beginning:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

I know how to add for the first time html into my empty div using jQuery:

```
$('#mydiv').html('my html!');
```

But my problem is that I don't know how to push more html at the end of my non-empty div:

```
 <div id="mydiv">my html!**how to add more html here**</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$('#mydiv').html('my html!');
$('#mydiv').append('more html!');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#mydiv').append($('**how to add more html here**'));
```

For adding it at the beginning use prepend.

Comment: You can pass a string to append without calling jQuery on it.

Comment: Wasn't sure, so I thought I'd add it anyway.  Meh.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty straightforward:

```
$("#mydiv").html($("#mydiv").html() + " I want to add html here");
```

Comment: Ah didn't realise there is append as well. Oh well :).