# how to update form structure using ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Recently i have been working over a contact module.There are 3 columns ie. `name`, `email`, `phone` and a `+1` button which includes anew row to add one more contact filed using ajax.
And here the problem arise. **When i update my structure, the data in old contact field vanishes.**

Eg:

I entered 2 rows and filled the data as name1, email1, and so on..

```
name1 email1 phone1
name2 email2 phone2
```

Now in order to add one more contact filed i use `+1` botton. and as soon i click it i get:

```
blank_1 blank_1 blank_1
blank_2 blank_2 blank_2
blank_3 blank_3 blank_3   //here blank_1, blank_2, blank_3 are just expressing blank columns
```

**My jquery code is :**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
num = 0;

$('#plus_contact').click(function(e) {
    num = num +1 ;
    $.ajax({
        url : 'contact/contact_form.php',
        method : 'POST',
        data : "number="+num,
        success : function(data) {
                    $('#contact_form_div').html(data);
                },
    });
});
}); </script>
```

**contact_form.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['number']) && is_numeric($_POST['number']))
{

    echo $list =$_POST['number'];
    if($list == 1)
    {
        for($i=0; $i<$list;$i++)
        {
        ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="c_name[]" class="form-control" id="c_full_name" placeholder="Full  Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" name="c_email[]" class="form-control" id="c_email_id"  placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Phone</label>
            <input type="tel" name="c_phone[]" class="form-control" id="c_phone_number" placeholder="Phone">
        </div>
        <?php
        }
    } } ?>
```

**How can i add a row without altering the old row data ??**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add "more" html at then end of an element using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042106/add-more-html-at-then-end-of-an-element-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this:

```
 $('#contact_form_div').html(data);
```

with this :

```
 $('#contact_form_div').append(data);
```

You just need to append it not to replace it. hope it help :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing:

```
$('#contact_form_div').html(data);
```

Do this:

```
$('#contact_form_div').append(data);
```

Then you just need to make sure on your PHP that you only return one new row.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of replacing the current form, append the new lines generated by your PHP script. So you need to use `$('#contact_form_div').append(data);` instead of `$('#contact_form_div').html(data);`.

After you change that, you can use the `num` parameter to specify the number of rows to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask for the whole form on every request. Keep the page you have now to do the first load of the form when you load the page.

Then, make a php page that outputs a **single row** of results, request it via ajax as you have done, then [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the result to the current html of the page.